# Cide to know if a triangle is right-angled or not the math works fine but can't seem to get the value from the input

Tags: javascript, html

I tried changing the value into an integer with `parseInt` it still didn't work and whenever I run it it always just says `NaN`.

I tried changing the variables `a1`, `b1` and `c1` to `number` directly by (writing `a1 = 3` for example) and it worked fine then. I'm still a novice and I don't know what to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body> 
<h1> Find c or know if it's a right-angle triangle?</h1>
<div id="isIt">
   <h5>Please enter the lengths of each side.</h5>
//input area where you enter the sides of the triangle
<input id="a" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="a">
<input id="b" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="b">
<input id="c" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="c"> 
<br>
<button onclick="isIt()">is it a Triangle?</button>
<button onclick="findc()">What is c?</button>
</div>
<p id="answer"></p>
 <script>
 //where my problem is
 var a1 = (document.getElementById('a').value;
 var b1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
 var c1 = document.getElementById('c').value;
 var m = Math.sqrt( a1*a1 + b1*b1);

 //function to know if its a triangle
 function isIt() {
    if (c1 === m) {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'YES!';
    }else{
    var trueC0 =  Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b));
    var trueC2 = trueC0.toString();
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "NO! c needs to be " + trueC2 + " too be a 
    right-angle triangle";

}
}
//function to calculate c
function findc() {

var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b);
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = c.toString() ;
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited your title to be more explaining what you actually want to achieve. Also edited the text as it contained a lot of stuff that was not needed or was unclear in what you wanted to explain. I hope that helps to understand your question way better now.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with this code. First is that you're declaring var `a1 b1 c1` and `m` outside your `isIt` function. So those variables are created and initialized only when your code loads and not in every call to `isIt`. That means that when you call `isIt` those variables aren't updated with the new values on the inputs and the calculations are made with whatever value they had on page load. Second is that here `var trueC0 =  Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b))` and here `var c = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b);` you're using var `a` and `b` which doesn't exist. That's the reason why it returns `Nan`. I believe they should be `a1` and `b1`. Here is the working code:

```js
<script>
    //function to know if its a triangle
    function isIt() {

      var a1 = document.getElementById('a').value;
      var b1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
      var c1 = document.getElementById('c').value;
      var m = Math.sqrt(a1 * a1 + b1 * b1);

      if (c1 === m) {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'YES!';
      } else {
        var trueC0 = Math.sqrt((a1 * a1) + (b1 * b1));
        var trueC2 = trueC0.toString();
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "NO! c needs to be " + trueC2 + " too be a right-angle triangle";
      }
    }
    //function to calculate c
    function findc() {

      var a1 = document.getElementById('a').value;
      var b1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
      var c1 = document.getElementById('c').value;
      var m = Math.sqrt(a1 * a1 + b1 * b1);

      var c = Math.sqrt(a1 * a1 + b1 * b1);
      document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = c.toString();
    }
  </script>
```

Also note that here `if (c1 === m)` `c1` and `m` can be floating numbers and Javascript has issues with floating numbers comparison. It is very common that it returns false even when the numbers are equal. There are libraries for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>
<body> 
<h1> Find c or know if it's a right-angle triangle?</h1>
<div id="isIt">
   <h5>Please enter the lengths of each side.</h5>
//input area where you enter the sides of the triangle
<input id="a" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="a">
<input id="b" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="b">
<input id="c" type="number" min="0.1" placeholder="c"> 
<br>
<button onclick="isIt()">is it a Triangle?</button>
<button onclick="findc()">What is c?</button>
</div>
<p id="answer"></p>
 <script>
 //where my problem is
 

 //function to know if its a triangle
 function isIt() {
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var c1 = document.getElementById('c').value;
    var m = Math.sqrt( a1*a1 + b1*b1);
    if (c1 == m) {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'YES!';
    }else{
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "NO! c needs to be " + m + " too be a right-angle triangle"

}
}
//function to calculate c
function findc() {
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var b1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var c = Math.sqrt( a1*a1 + b1*b1);
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = c;
}
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

When the script loads, your a1,b1,c1 and m initialized, but at that time, user haven't entered any value, so all of them are undefined. When function isIt and findC execute, they are using undefined values for calculation. That's why your code doesn't work. Also m is a number, but c1 is string, you will need == to compare them, or you need to cast c1 to number if you want to use === for comparing them.

Hope it helps